# Obtener datos de diferentes tablas de una base de datos mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, select, mpdf

Hola buenas noches a todos, tengo un problema al realizar una consulta en mysql desde php.
Básicamente mi sistema realizará reportes de una base de datos, misma que está estructurada así:

**Tabla Perfiles**

```
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| idperfil    | int(4)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| username    | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| password    | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| nombres     | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| appaterno   | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| apmaterno   | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| curp        | varchar(18) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| fechanac    | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| entidadnac  | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sexo        | varchar(9)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| institucion | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| privilegios | varchar(8)  | YES  |     | Alumno  |       |
| foto        | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| estado      | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**Tabla Contactos**

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| idcontacto | int(4)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| idperfil   | int(4)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| calleynum  | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| colonia    | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| municipio  | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| estado     | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| telfijo    | varchar(12) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| telcelular | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| email      | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**Tabla Inscripciones**

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| matricula    | varchar(12) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| idperfil     | int(4)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| idexpediente | int(4)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| niveledu     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| fechains     | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| fechaini     | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| asesor       | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| horario      | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**Tabla Tutores**

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| idtutor    | int(4)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| matricula  | varchar(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tnombres   | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tappaterno | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tapmaterno | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| direccion  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| telefono   | varchar(12) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Estoy utilizando la librería **mpdf** para poder generar el **PDF** de la inscripción, este es el código del generador:

**Archivo generarHojaInscripcion.php**

```
<?php
require_once('Connections/conexion.php');
include_once("mpdf/mpdf.php");
$matricula = $_GET['matricula'];
$fecha = date("d-m-Y");
$consulta = "SELECT inscripciones.matricula, perfiles.nombres, perfiles.appaterno, perfiles.apmaterno, calleynum, colonia, municipio, telfijo, telcelular, fechanac, sexo, email, institucion, tnombres, tappaterno, tapmaterno, direccion, telefono, fechains, niveledu, fechaini, horario FROM perfiles, contactos, inscripciones, tutores WHERE inscripciones.matricula='$matricula',  group by inscripciones.matricula;";
if($buscardatos = $mysqli->query($consulta)){
        $datos = $buscardatos->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $buscardatos->free();
    }

else {
        printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
        $mysqli->close();
        exit;
    }

$mpdf = new mPDF('R','A4', 11,'Arial');
$mpdf -> SetTitle('Inscripcion de '.$datos['matricula'].'');
$mpdf -> WriteHTML('<body>');
$mpdf -> WriteHTML('<br><br><br>
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="2" align="right">Matricula: <strong><em>'.$datos['matricula'].'</em></strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="2" align="right">Fecha de impresión: <strong><em>'.$fecha.'</em></strong></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
');
$mpdf -> WriteHTML('<h2 style="text-align: center">DATOS GENERALES DEL ALUMNO</h2>');
$mpdf -> WriteHTML('
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="right">Nombre(s): </td>
      <td colspan="2" align="left"><strong>'.$datos['nombres'].'</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="right">Apellido Paterno: </td>
      <td colspan="2" align="left"><strong>'.$datos['appaterno'].'</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="right">Apellido Materno: </td>
      <td colspan="2" align="left"><strong>'.$datos['apmaterno'].'</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="right">Direccion: </td>
      <td colspan="2" align="left"><strong>'.$datos['calleynum'].'</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="20%" align="right">Colonia: </td>
      <td width="30%" align="left"><strong>'.$datos['colonia'].'</strong></td>
      <td width="20%" align="right">Municipio: </td>
      <td width="30%" align="left"><strong>'.$datos['municipio'].'</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Telefono: </td>
      <td align="left"><strong>'.$datos['telfijo'].'</strong></td>
      <td align="right">Celular: </td>
      <td align="left"><strong>'.$datos['telcelular'].'</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Fecha de nacimiento: </td>
      <td align="left"><strong>'.$datos['fechanac'].'</strong></td>
      <td align="right">Sexo: </td>
      <td align="left"><strong>'.$datos['sexo'].'</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Correo: </td>
      <td align="left"><strong>'.$datos['email'].'</strong></td>
      <td align="right">Institución: </td>
      <td align="left"><strong>'.$datos['institucion'].'</strong></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
');
$mpdf -> WriteHTML('<h2 style="text-align: center">DATOS DEL TUTOR</h2>');
$mpdf -> WriteHTML('
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="right">Nombre(s): </td>
      <td colspan="2" align="left"><strong>'.$datos['tnombres'].'</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="right">Apellido Paterno: </td>
      <td colspan="2" align="left"><strong>'.$datos['tappaterno'].'</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="right">Apellido Materno: </td>
      <td colspan="2" align="left"><strong>'.$datos['tapmaterno'].'</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="15%" align="right">Direccion: </td>
      <td width="35%" align="left"><strong>'.$datos['direccion'].'</strong></td>
      <td width="25%" align="right">Telefono: </td>
      <td width="25%" align="left"><strong>'.$datos['telefono'].'</strong></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
');
$mpdf -> WriteHTML('<h2 style="text-align: center">DATOS DE LA INSCRIPCIÓN</h2>');
$mpdf -> WriteHTML('
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="right">Fecha de inscripción: </td>
      <td colspan="2" align="left"><strong>'.$datos['fechains'].'</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="20%" align="right">Curso solicitado: </td>
      <td width="30%" align="left"><strong>'.$datos['niveledu'].'</strong></td>
      <td width="20%" align="right">Fecha de inicio: </td>
      <td width="30%" align="left"><strong>'.$datos['fechaini'].'</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Pago: </td>
      <td align="left"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
      <td align="right">Horario: </td>
      <td align="left"><strong>'.$datos['horario'].'</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Inscripción: </td>
      <td align="left"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
      <td align="right">Colegiatura: </td>
      <td align="left"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
');
$mpdf -> WriteHTML('</body>');
$mpdf -> Output('Insc-'.$datos['matricula'].'.pdf', 'I');
exit;
?>
```

Sin embargo al generar el archivo, me muestra datos de otra inscripción y no de la que yo quiero realizar, en este caso la inscripción sería de la alumna **Maria Fernanda**, sin embargo salen datos de la inscripción de **Alejandro Garcia**, aquí les muestro:

[image: Confirmación de inscripción]
[image: Al generar el PDF se muestran los datos de otra inscripción]

Podrían ayudarme, por favor. Me parece que mi problema es en la **sentencia mysql**, pues la única información correcta que muestra es la que se muestra en **Datos de inscripción**.

Comment: Como relacionas las tablas Tutores con otra, es por el campo "matricula"?. Tutores.matricula = Inscripciones.matricula?

Comment: Así es, relaciono la tabla a través del campo matricula.@juliocpiro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Busca los datos segun la tabla **Perfil** que es la tabla donde parten los datos del alumno.

```
//obten el perfil
$perfil = $_GET['perfil'];

//Query que devuelve los mismo campos solo se modifico el WHERE y se quito GROUP BY
$consulta = "SELECT ins.matricula, pe.nombres, pe.appaterno, pe.apmaterno, co.calleynum, co.colonia, co.municipio, co.telfijo, co.telcelular, pe.fechanac, pe.sexo, co.email, pe.institucion, tu.tnombres, tu.tappaterno, tu.tapmaterno, tu.direccion, tu.telefono, ins.fechains, ins.niveledu, ins.fechaini, ins.horario FROM Inscripciones ins LEFT JOIN Perfiles pe ON pe.idperfil=ins.idperfil LEFT JOIN Contactos co ON co.idperfil = pe.idperfil LEFT JOIN Tutores tu ON tu.matricula = ins.matricula WHERE pe.perfil='$perfil';";
```

En este archivo no debes modificar ninguna otra linea, en el archivo previo a este donde envias el parametro `matricula` modificalo para que ahora envia `perfil`. Espero te sirva.

Comment: La verdad estaba investigando como obtener sólo un registro de la tabla, pues al ejecutarla sin el _group by_ aparecían más de 6 mil registros. Y no conozco el porqué pones los prefijos _in._ , _pe._ y _co._ antes de cada campo, podrías explicarme por favor?

Comment: Son alias, los pongo despues de cada tabla por ejemplo en FROM Inscripciones *in*

Comment: Y efectivamente, la coma no estaba en el script original, no sé como apareció ahí, pero en si no debe de estar.

Comment: Si te devuelve mas de 6 mil registros entonces no es la forma adecuada, descarta el group by. Si estas buscando los datos de una persona entonces buscalo segun la tabla **perfil**, actualizare mi respuesta.

Comment: Ya realicé todas las modificaciones en los otros archivos y me marca el siguiente error:
`Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'in LEFT JOIN Perfiles pe ON pe.idperfil=in.idperfil LEFT JOIN Contactos co ON co' at line 1`

Comment: acabo de modificar "in" por "ins", prueba asi

Comment: Quedó perfecto, ahora funciona muy bien, sólo aclarar para los que les sirva la pregunta que tengo un error en la estructura de mi base de datos, pues el campo matricula en una tabla es de 11 y en otra de 12, por lo que no me mostraba los registros correctamente, modificandola funciona perfecto, gracias Julio :)